# Image of Joukowski Map on Annulus and Quarter Disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the image of the following two regions under the map $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+ \frac{1}{z})$.

a) The annulus $\{z: \frac{1}{2} < |z| < 1\}$

b) The quarter disk $\{z: |z| <1, \text{ and } x>0,y>0\}$

I've been able to recreate the steps outlined here: [Joukowski mapping a circle onto an ellipse problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651865/joukowski-mapping-a-circle-onto-an-ellipse-problem). Therefore, since $w= (1/2)[(r+ 1/r)\cos(\theta) + i (r-1/r)\sin(\theta)]$, we can let $u=(1/2)(r+1/r)\cos(\theta)$ and $v=(1/2)(r-1/r)\sin(\theta)$ to get $$ \frac{u^2}{[(1/2)(r+1/r)]^2} + \frac{v^2}{[(1/2)(r-1/r)]^2} =1$$

But then I'm tempted to just say that the image of the annulus given in part a) is simply just the set of all ellipses given above such that $1/2 < r < 1$. And then for part b) we have the set consisting of the intersection of the first quadrant with ellipses of the form above such that $0<r<1$. This seems pretty logical to me, but I feel like I'm somehow missing some further simplification. Meaning, part b) seems to not even add anything to the problem other than having me specify a different range for my $r$-parameter and restricting to the first quadrant. Does this answer seem sufficient or have I missed something?

Comment: Your description for a) can be simplified if you consider what happens when $r \to 1^-$. For b), let $\mathbb Q_1 = \{x + i y: x > 0 \land y > 0\}$. It's not true that $f(\mathbb D \cap \mathbb Q_1) = f(\mathbb D) \cap \mathbb Q_1$. It's not true that $f(\mathbb D \cap \mathbb Q_1) = f(\mathbb D) \cap f(\mathbb Q_1)$ either, only that $f(\mathbb D \cap \mathbb Q_1) \subseteq f(\mathbb D) \cap f(\mathbb Q_1)$.

Comment: @Maxim I see what you mean for part b). Now, for part a), as $r$ approaches $1$ from the left, $v^2$ is being multiplied by a term which is blowing up. So it looks like for our equation to hold, $v$ must go to $0$ as $r \rightarrow 1$. What I'm picturing is an ellipse that's getting compressed until we're left with a line segment that goes from $u=-1$ to $u=1$.

Comment: Correct, we get the interior of the ellipse corresponding to $r = 1/2$ minus the segment $[-1, 1]$. For b), $r$ changes from $0$ to $1$ and $\theta$ changes from $0$ to $\pi/2$.